# Kendo UI File Uploader Form Empty

Tags: php, file, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am converting an existing application to use a kendo file uploader, but the uploader does not submit the file. Here is the relevant HTML:

```
        <div class="form-sort large bottom-radius">
            <!-- Attachment form -->
                <input type="file"  multiple="multiple"  name="attachments[]" id="addProjectAttachments" class="project-input" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px; z-index: -9999;" data-key="files" />
                <small class="error">Please provide a project attachment</small>
            <!-- /Attachment form -->
        </div>
```

the relevant JS:

```
        /**
         * Initialize Kendo Upload
         * @external 'kendoUpload()'
         * @see {@link https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/index}
         */
        $inputAttachments.kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: '/upload/add',
                removeUrl: '/upload/remove',
                autoUpload: true
            },
            success: onSuccess,
            remove: onRemove
        });
```

The page makes and ajax request to the proper endpoint `/upload/add` but the form submitted doesn't have the file. Here is a screenshot of what the uploader submits to the server:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

How do I get the file uploader to actually send the file?

UPDATE: Just to reinforce the fact that nothing is being received on the other end, the following are all empty `$_FILES`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` , `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Also the request size itself is only 672B when the image is about 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

Such Payloads may sometimes not be displayed correctly  in Chorme's developers tool - when I test with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for example on [this demo](https://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/upload/async) I can see the following Payload when I upload a text file with text 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA':

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryxjprkqww7bTpl1IF Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="testUpload.txt" Content-Type:
>   text/plain
>
> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryxjprkqww7bTpl1IF--

Comment: That example is the PHP Kendo Library, not the Javascript Library. Also the contents of `$_FILES`, `$_POST` and `file_get_contents('php://input')` are all empty. Also the request size itself is only 672B when the image is about 2MB.

Comment: I have just tested the PHP code provided below the linked demo and it worked correctly at my side - here is a [video](https://www.screencast.com/t/ZImBVXCKj7oi).

Comment: Please use Kendo UI https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload not Kendo PHP. The example provided uses the wrong library.

Comment: Kendo UI is actually used under the hood of the PHP wrappers too. Yet I have tested it with the jQuery librtary and it worked the same way on the official [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/async) - here is the [video](https://www.screencast.com/t/XWun2s7I).

Comment: I did the samething you did. created a file with AAAAA in it and uploaded it. You can see by the payload description that its not properly included:

------WebKitFormBoundarydnbBBwX9lCwrK3cA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundarydnbBBwX9lCwrK3cA--

Answer (score 0):

<input type="file"  multiple="multiple"  name="attachments[]" id="addProjectAttachments"

try set both name and id same, name="attachments" id="attachments"